# Deploying reports: columns-field: Invalid value specified: BUSINESS_DURATION

Tags: deployment, businesshours

In my CI/CD pipeline, when I deploy from Org A -> version control -> Org B after developing a report in Org A, I get the following error for the report in question

```
columns-field: Invalid value specified: BUSINESS_DURATION. 
columns-aggregateTypes: Invalid value specified: BUSINESS_DURATION. 
customAggregates: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Field BUSINESS_DURATION:SUM does not exist. 
Check spelling. chart-column: Invalid value specified: FORMULA1.
```

The report is on OOTB Report type `Case Lifecycle` and includes columns for:

- `Case History Status`
- `Duration`
- `Subject`
- `Account Name`
- `Date/Time Opened`
- `Business Hours Duration`
- `Avg Age` - a summary level formula column defined as `BUSINESS_DURATION:SUM/OPEN:SUM`

Both source and target orgs have Business Hours enabled

What causes this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target org needs to have `Enable Case duration or age in business hours` enabled.

In my use case, this target org was a full copy sandbox created before the Production org had `Enable Case duration or age in business hours` switched on so that configuration didn't automatically flow into the full copy sandbox.

Per the [Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387290&type=1), you need to **file a support case to enable this**. This will expose the `Business Hours Duration` field for reports.

> How to request the activation of this feature
>
> Have a system administrator create a Support Case with the Feature Activations & Limits Team. Our Support Team will review the Case and action the request as needed.
>
> Note:
>
> If a User has their access to the 'Closed Date/Time' field limited through Field Level Security or Field Accessibility then this field will not be available for use.
> The Business Hours Age field is a reporting field that is not editable at the record level and cannot be used as a filter or bucket field in a report.
> The regular "Age" field will still be visible in Case object reports even after enabling the feature "Enable Case Duration/Age in Business Hours."